# How do I return TRUE or FALSE from MySQL within PHP function?

Tags: php, function, if-statement

I am experimenting with PHP. This is my func.php

```
function returnBlankStylist(){

$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `".$dbn."`.`stylist` WHERE `stylist`.`customer_id`='1'");
if (mysql_affected_rows()==0) {
 return false;
} else {
 return true;
}
}
```

This is my page.tpl

```
<?php if (returnBlankStylist==false){?>
<div class="center graybox"> Please enjoy this discount since this you have never filled out a query before</div>
<? }?>
```

If the customer Id 1 exists it shows the message, and if the customer Id 1 does not exist it shows the message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Page.tpl

```
<?php if (returnBlankStylist() == false) : ?>
    <div class="center graybox">
        Please enjoy this discount since this you have never filled out a query before
    </div>
<? endif; ?>
```

or

```
<?php if (!returnBlankStylist()) : ?>
    <div class="center graybox">
        Please enjoy this discount since this you have never filled out a query before
    </div>
<? endif; ?>
```

or

```
<?php if (returnBlankStylist() == false) { ?>
    <div class="center graybox">
        Please enjoy this discount since this you have never filled out a query before
    </div>
<? } ?>
```

Comment: Why the dots and calling the function again within the IF?

Comment: returnBlankStylist alone doesn't do anything, you need to call it by adding the (). The dots don't really matter, it just looks better ;)

Comment: @TheBlackBenzKid it's just an [alternative syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php)

Answer (score 1):

you have missed parenthises ..

```
if(returnBlankStylist()==false){
    //your code...
}
```

hope it will work for you

Answer (score 1):

Please replace your code `if (mysql_affected_rows()==0)` to `if (mysql_num_rows()==0);`

and try this:

```
<?php if (!returnBlankStylist()){?>
<div class="center graybox"> Please enjoy this discount since this you have never filled out a query before</div>
<? }?>
```

Comment: repped for efforts – I prefer the ! when it can be used for performance and less characters